# Why do routes created in a React router that do not exist in Drupal give a 404 when I reload the browser?

Tags: blocks, uri, 10

I have a `Drupal 10` site with one page at the following URL: `localhost:9090/my-page`. On that page, I have a `Drupal block` that includes a `React app` with its own `Browser Router`.

React **BrowserRouter** configuration:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/my-page">
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

React **Routes**:

```
<Routes>
  <Route index path="/demo-1" element={<DemoOne />} />
  <Route path="/demo-2" element={<DemoTwo />} />
</Routes>
```

When I access the `My Page`, the `React App` shows up, and I can use `React Router` normally, and the **URL changes**. The problem occurs when I **reload the page**; Drupal gives me a **404 error**.

Example: **localhost:9090/my-page/demo-1**

I'm using `Nginx`, and perhaps I need some extra configuration for this scenario.

**Final Note:**

React APP is embed directly inside Drupal page with **[Drupal Block Plugin](https://www.rapiddg.com/article/how-add-react-widget-drupal-8-site)**. So there is no **index.html**.

This is an example what I exactly need:

https://iap.unido.org/data/sdg-9-industry?p=LBY

Base is `/data` and `/data/sdg-9-industry` is some page inside `React`.

Comment: If there isn’t a Drupal page at that URL there will be a 404.

Comment: Hi @cilefen i understand that. But how it works when i access demo-1 from /my-page? thank you

Comment: That’s because React router is making it appear as if you made a GET request there. That’s how JavaScript routers work—they do not always make HTTP requests.

Comment: Ok, do you have any suggestion or workaround to get this works or that's impossible? :/ Btw this is an example of Drupal CMS with React. Content area is React component /data 

https://iap.unido.org/data/sdg-9-industry?p=LBY

Comment: Drupal Answers is a question-and-answer site. It is not a support forum or a discussion board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 404 because JavaScript routers can create paths in the browser which do not actually exist on the backend web application, and the router pushes those paths onto the browser history. For this to not be a 404 when reloading the browser, create the path on the Drupal site also.

This is nothing to do with Drupal specifically.